# How to initialise an object which is inside nsmutablearray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have 10 `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` instances for downloading 10 files concurrently.

Each instances are named differently (For ex. downloadTask1,downloadTask2,etc..)

I initialised them as follows,

```
self.downloadTask1 = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL url1]]
self.downloadTask2 = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL url2]]
self.downloadTask3 = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL url3]]
.
. 
self.downloadTask10 = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL url10]]
```

This takes 10 lines. Now my question is,

Can i do that in single line by adding each `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` instances in `NSMutableArray`.

This is what i tried

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
[self.downloadTaskArray objectAtIndex:i] = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL [self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i]]
}
```

I know the above method is wrong. The error which i faced is **Expression is not Assignable**.

I hope you understood my problem. Is is possible to achieve what i am trying ?

> Note : I definitely want to use different name for downloadTask
>   because i need to identify them later in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    [self.downloadTaskArray addObject:[self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL [self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Comment: What if i want to re-initialise a particular object ?

Comment: [self.downloadTaskArray insertObject:newObject atIndex:index]; The newObject is the object you re-init, and the index is its position.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask* task = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.downloadTaskArray addObject:task];
}
```

Comment: i need different instance name.... Your code will name all instances as  **task**

Comment: Then you don't need an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask* task = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[self.urlArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        task.taskIdentifier = i;//To keep track of download task in current session.(an identifier for this task, assigned by and unique to the owning session)
        [self.downloadTaskArray addObject:task];
    }
```

You can reinitiate object by accessing it from taskIdentifier.

Comment: isn't it enough to access the task simply by [self.downloadTaskArray objectAtIndex:]?

Comment: He wanted something unique associated with task to identify them. So taskIdentifier can be good option.